# After creating folder return data is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, sharepoint-framework

I using the code below, but and the script that creates the folder on my SP online server is working just fine, but the problem is that return `data` is `undefined`

```
$.when(pCreate(path + "/" + name)).always(function (data) {
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
});
var pCreate = function (pathAndName) {
    getFormDigest(pageContent.web.absoluteUrl).then(function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            "url": pageContent.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add('Shared Documents" + CustomerStartingFolder + pathAndName + "')",
            "type": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Can someone point out what is wrong since I dont get the return data of the created folder?

Comment: pCreate seems to not have a callback method from the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert stated, AJAX is async and returns data via a callback method. Something like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    "url": "/sites/yourSite/_api/Web/Folders/add('Shared Documents/TestFolder')",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-length": 0,
        "X-RequestDigest": "yourRequestDigestGoesHere"
    },
    "success" : function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)) },
    "error" : function(err){ alert(JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 4)) }
}
);
```